# Как выключить жесты на android, на платформе MAUI?

Tags: android, xamarin, maui

Дело в том что Navigation реагирует на жесты с Android, и выходит с ContentPage, даже если я не указываю кнопку выхода.
В интернете пишут только как выключить панель навигации, про жесты ни слова.

Буду рад любому работающему способу.

Дело в том что там еще работа с 21 API и новых 30API, есть решение которое не работает, в обоих случаях.

Answer (score 0):

Зайдите в Platforms/Android/MainActivity.cs и добавьте туда этот код:

```
public override bool OnKeyDown([GeneratedEnum] Keycode keyCode, KeyEvent e)
{
    if (keyCode == Keycode.Back) return true;
    return base.OnKeyDown(keyCode, e);
}
```

Таким образом приложение не будет возвращаться на предыдущую страницу по жесту с края экрана или по нажатию системной кнопки назад.